# Different behaviour for `vi` and `sudo vi`

Tags: vimrc

On my Raspberry 3 running `Raspbian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)` I get different behaviour for vim depending if I use `vim file` or `sudo vim file`.

Especially two things:

1. With `sudo vim` I can use the `Page Up` and `Page Down` keys to go forward and backwards a page. Without `sudo` I can't.
2. After I close a file, without `sudo` the terminal shows the last part of the file I was just in, and without `sudo` it doesn't.
3. I `set hlsearch` in my `.vimrc`, but when I use `sudo` the searched terms don't get highlighted, without `sudo` they do.

I want the `sudo` behaviour (except for point 3) without having to use `sudo` all the time (because of obvious reasons), but I don't even know where to start. Is it a problem with my terminal, is it a problem with my vim?

My .vimrc:

```
set term=ansi
syntax on
set hlsearch
```

I hope somebody has an idea what is happening here...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that as a workaround you can explicitly specify a vimrc file when you launch with `vim -u <vimrc>`. But I'm sure you want to find a more permanent "fix".

I can't tell you exactly what is going on with your system except that it's likely related to environment differences between sudo and non-sudo runs. Here's some info to help you investigate further...

Start by looking at `:help vimrc`. This describes how `vim` finds vimrc files. It's system dependent (e.g. Unix looks in `$HOME/.vimrc` first, Windows `$HOME/_vimrc`). You'll want to check, for example, the value of `$HOME` when running with/without `sudo`.

To get some ideas about what is being loaded you can run `:scriptnames` from vim. This shows all scripts that have been loaded, in order. Look near the top of the output as that's usually where loading of your vimrc file appears.

You can also do `vim -Vn` which will print out useful information depending on value of *n*:

```
>= 1    When the viminfo file is read or written.
>= 2    When a file is ":source"'ed.
>= 5    Every searched tags file and include file.
>= 8    Files for which a group of autocommands is executed.
>= 9    Every executed autocommand.
>= 12   Every executed function.
>= 13   When an exception is thrown, caught, finished, or discarded.
>= 14   Anything pending in a ":finally" clause.
>= 15   Every executed Ex command (truncated at 200 characters).
```

**Update:** minnmass' [helpful answer](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/13927/11054) led me to a fact I wasn't aware of. I knew that `sudo -e`/`sudoedit` helps protect against accidental clobbering of critical files by using temp files but I didn't know this: *unlike most commands run by sudo, the editor is run with the **invoking user's environment unmodified.*** So you may be able to keep `$HOME/.vimrc` and do `sudo -e <file>`. Give it a try if you are so inclined. (Depending on exiting values, you may first need to do `export ENVVAR=vim` where `ENVVAR` is any one of `SUDO_EDITOR`, `VISUAL` or `EDITOR`.)

Comment: Thank you very much. When using `:scriptnames` I can see that `sudo vi` doesnt load the `~/.vimrc`, only the `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` and `vi` loads `/usr/shar/vim/vimrc` but after that it loads `~/.vimrc`. Deleting the `~/.vimrc` and putting `set hlsearch` into the `/usr/share/vim/vimrc` fixed everything. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

You're running `vim` as root, not as your normal user (that's what `sudo` does). Since you're not running `vim` as your normal user, your user's .vimrc isn't being consulted (this is the correct, expected behavior).

If you need to edit a file as root, but want to use your regular editor and configuration, look at `sudo -e` or `sudoedit` (which is basically an alias to `sudo -e`). The man page ([here](https://www.sudo.ws/man/1.8.18/sudo.man.html#e), or just `man sudo`) may be useful in configuring your system to use `vim` for that purpose.

Comment: +1 for using sudo -e, which also prevents the otherwise trivial method of getting a root shell from a root file editor using :shell.

Answer (score 0):

Per what minnmass said above, running vi as root (using `sudo`) will bypass your ~/.vimrc.

You can however specify your own vimrc while running vi with sudo.

Add the following lines to your ~/.bashrc.

```
alias sudo='sudo '
alias vis='vi -u ~/.vimrc'
```

After sourcing the bashrc, you should be able to run `sudo vis <filename>`, and keep your regular vi editor behavior in superuser.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Just note that you could use `sudo -e` without all the alias fuss, which still doesn't correctly process any files I have in `~/.vim`.